# How do I install Termkit?

Tags: software-installation

I spend most of my time in the terminal. I heard something about [TermKit](http://acko.net/blog/on-termkit), and I'm curious as to how I can install it on Ubuntu. So far, I haven't been able to find any good instructions on how to install it.

Comment: Thanks for this... Installing it myself, I will post an answer as soon as I make it work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install git libssl-dev
```

Now, download, build and install node, npm (a package manager for node) and TermKit itself:

#### Build Node.js:

trunk is a bit unstable so we check out a known-working version of node:

```
cd ~
mkdir TermKitProj
cd TermKitProj
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
git reset --hard 1b8dd65d6e3b82b6863e
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..
git clone http://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm
sudo make install
cd ..
```

#### Build TermKit

```
git clone https://github.com/Floby/TermKit.git --recursive
cd TermKit/
npm install
```

Okay, everything is installed. Now lets launch it!

```
node Node/nodekit.js
```

You should see something like this:

```
18 Jun 20:12:45 - socket.io ready - accepting connections
server listening at http://localhost:2222
```

And now navigate to http://localhost:2222 in Chrome/Chromium (Firefox won't work, webkit needed!)
To launch it again, navigate to TermKitProj/TermKit and run  "node Node/nodekit.js" again.

Thanks to [this guide](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/06/termkit-is-terminal-reimagined-install.html).

Comment: I am getting the following error `node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick` `TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous>`